# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when right clicking an Entry widget

Tags: windows, rust, gtk, gtk3

I am using the `gtk` cargo package version `0.17.1` to build a desktop application for windows. My Installed GTK version is `3.24.37`. I use an `Entry` widget in my window and, when debugging, I attempt to click the widget 3 times. Sometimes it will freeze after the first right click, the right click menu will not popup and the program will crash with the following error:

`process didn't exit successfully: ... (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)`

Sometimes this occurs after 3 right clicks. I am also experiencing the same crash and variable frequency upon trying to paste UTF-8 text into the Entry.

```
    let groupname_box = SearchEntry::builder()
        .placeholder_text(GROUP_PLACEHOLDER)
        .width_request(windows::WIDTH)
        .build();

    let scroll_window = ScrolledWindow::builder()
        .width_request(WIDTH)
        .height_request(HEIGHT)
        .hscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Never)
        .vscrollbar_policy(PolicyType::Automatic)
        .child(&defaultsbox)
        .build();

    let view = GtkBox::builder()
        .orientation(Orientation::Horizontal)
        .child(&button_box)
        .child(&scroll_window)
        .build();

    groupname_box.connect_paste_clipboard(move |box_context| {
        log("token box pasted");
    });

    groupname_box.connect_button_release_event(move |_, _| {
        Inhibit(false)
    });
```

Please advise the best way to fix this behaviour. Is this a bug that was fixed in GTK4? Am I handling user input events badly? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to known bug types [in GTK3](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5678). I have upgraded to GTK4 which has fixed all these crashes.